# Hiding soft keys, notification area, and clock in Android 3.1

Tags: android

The built-in photo gallery hides the soft keys (back, home, etc.), clock, and notification area at the bottom of the screen, but I can't seem to hide them myself in Android 3.1, even with:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility(int)

With these constants: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN

When using this, if your own UI is changing along with it (such as happens in Books), you'll want to use this to drive those changes so you stay in sync with the status bar: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener.html